# Is there any native method to fix screen recordings when you have a vertifcal primary monitor?

Tags: video, display, multiple-monitors, screen-capture, orientation

Due to certain circumstances, my monitors are in a vertical + horizontal setup, with my primary being vertical.  When I take any screen recordings, [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A9ebXLxVxcJWzeEPQeAfFMZQpK9HNRwf/view?usp=sharing) always seems to happen, specifically the misalignment of the mouse pointer and the incorrect video orientation and aspect ratio in the outputted .mp4 file.

I'm using nVidia's Shadow Play / Instant Replay, and I'm not looking to switch to a 3rd party software or utility just to address this issue, and changing orientation also isn't a viable option for me.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: What you describe is a bug, as you don't want to avoid the bug (change layout / use different software) your only option is to report it and wait to be fixed. We can't help with that here, please contact nvidia.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because desired solution (improve software) is off-topic here.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I don't mind doing so, but are you actually certain the issue should be reported to nVidia rather than Microsoft?  Based on intuition alone, I had presumed the issue to be systemic rather than due to software, so some definitive feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Users here neither work for nvidia neither for Microsoft, so can't give a definite answer where to report. Maybe for both of them